# JSONObject as a member variable in POJO not recognized -Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, jackson, json

I'm building a RESTful web service. I've been locked in a situation where I'm not able to proceed. I've a DAO (a POJO) that has a `JSONObject` as a member variable. When I try to make a POST call from client (Postman or user-defined javascript) and try to debug, the value gathered in the getter of the `JSONObject` is empty ({}) whereas the other members of the class obtain their appropriate values. I've tried annotating the `JSONObject` and its getter with `@XmlElement`, `@JsonProperty` and so on.. Nothing worked.

The class looks like :

```
package org.somepackage

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

    import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect;
    import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;
    import org.json.JSONObject;


    @XmlRootElement

    public class someClass {
        private String someID;
        private String someName;

        private JSONObject someJsonObject;


        public someClass () {

        }
        public someClass (String id, String name,
                JSONObject jsonObj) {
            someID=id;
            someName=name;
            someJsonObject=jsonObj;

        }
        public String getSomeID() {
            return someID;
        }
        public void setSomeID(String id) {
            this.SomeID= id;
        }
        public String getSomeName() {
            return someName;
        }
        public void setSomeName(String name) {
            this.someName= name;
        }

        public JSONObject getSomeJsonObject() {
            return someJsonObject;
        }
        public void setSomeJsonObject(JSONObject jsonObj) {
            this.someJsonObject= jsonObj;
        }
    }
```

I appreciate your help!
Thanks.

---

**EDIT**

Example JSON

```
{ 
  "name": "ABCD", 
  "ID": "P63784433", 
  "theJSON":{
    "string":"foo",
    "number":5,
    "array":[1,2,3],
    "object":{
      "property":"value‌​",
      "subobj":{
        "arr":["foo","ha"],
        "numero":1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**DEPENDENCY**
web.xml dependency on Jackson

```
                        <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
                                <version>1.9.2</version>
                        </dependency>

                        <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
                                <version>1.9.2</version>
                        </dependency>

                         <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
                                <version>1.9.2</version>
                         </dependency>

                         <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
                                <version>1.9.2</version>
                        </dependency>

                        <dependency>
                                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                                <version>2.6.2</version>
                        </dependency>
```

---

**RESOURCES AND PROVIDER REGISTER through web.xml**

```
    <!-- Register JAX-RS Application -->
   <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>my.package.MyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <!-- Register resources and providers under my.package. -->
   <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>my.package</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <!-- Register custom provider  -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>my.package.mapper.ObjectMapperProvider</param-value>
    </init-param>`
```

---

**MyApplication.java**

```
`@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

public MyApplication() {
    // Register resources and providers using package-scanning.
    packages("my.package");

    register(ObjectMapperProvider.class);


}`
```

Comment: Create another nested POJO class to represent the data in the JSONObject, other wise for arbitrary data format, just use a `Map` instead of the `JSONObject`

Comment: Thanks @peeskillet , I followed your advice, but with no luck. The object is still parsed as an empty `JSONObject` no matter what are its contents.
Do you know if there's another way to go around this?
I need to consume the information as `JSON`, can a `Map` be used for this?

Comment: Share body and headers that you are passing with POST API

Comment: @peeskillet!
The JSON structure looks something like this:
`{
  "name": "ABCD",
  "ID": "P63784433",
  "theJSON":{"string":"foo","number":5,"array":[1,2,3],"object":{"property":"value","subobj":{"arr":["foo","ha"],"numero":1}}}
}`

Comment: @kyle , the body is what I've posted above this comment. Also with regards to the headers, I send back a response of this form:

`Response.ok(someString,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).status(201).header(CorsHeaderConstants.HEADER_AC_ALLOW_METHODS,"GET POST DELETE PUT").header(CorsHeaderConstants.HEADER_AC_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS,"true").header(CorsHeaderConstants.HEADER_AC_ALLOW_ORIGIN,"*").header(CorsHeaderConstants.HEADER_AC_ALLOW_ORIGIN,"*").allow("OPTIONS").build();`

I want to mention, my POST API has been working for other types of POJO,I'm stuck with just the one that contains a JSONObject!

Comment: Is this a set format for `"theJSON"` object? Or does it change? If it's set, why not just create some POJOs to map the properties?

Comment: @peeskillet I have an already built external library that parses `"theJSON" ` object .

Comment: What Jersey and Jackson version are you using? Please show your dependencies

Comment: @peeskillet Jersey version- 2.16  

Dependencies are:
`<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
<version>1.9.2</version>

<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
<version>1.9.2</version>
          
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
<version>1.9.2</version>

<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
<version>1.9.2</version>

<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
<version>2.6.2</version>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Jackson doesn't know how to create the `JSONObject` (at least not without some help). Jackson mainly handle basic type and POJOs. If you want to be able to handle `JSONObject` (assuming this is the object from `org.json`), you can add the [`jackson-datatype-json-org`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-json-org) for the Jackson support.

Below is a complete test. Here are the dependencies I used to test

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20141113</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-datatype-json-org</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Note:** The Jackson version I am using for `jackson-datatype-json-org` is the same Jackson version used by `jersey-media-json-jackson` 2.16. If you are using a different version of this jersey jackson, you will need to make sure the version of Jackson it pulls in is the same version of `jackson-datatype-json-org` you are using. This way we are not mixing Jackson versions.

Here's the test using [Jersey Test Framework](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html)

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsonorg.JsonOrgModule;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import org.junit.Test;
import static junit.framework.Assert.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Paul Samsotha
 */
public class JsonOrgTest extends JerseyTest {

    public static class Model {
        public String firstName;
        public String lastName;
        public JSONObject other;
        // should br private with correct getters and setters
    }

    @Path("model")
    public static class ModelResource {

        @POST
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response post(Model model) {
            return Response.ok(model).build();
        }
    }

    @Provider
    public static class ObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

        private final ObjectMapper mapper;

        public ObjectMapperProvider() {
            mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.registerModule(new JsonOrgModule());
        }

        @Override
        public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
            return mapper;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceConfig configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(ModelResource.class)
                .register(ObjectMapperProvider.class)
                .register(JacksonFeature.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClient(ClientConfig config) {
        config.register(JacksonFeature.class);
        config.register(ObjectMapperProvider.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void should_return_org_json_data() {
        final String json 
                = "{\n"
                + "  \"firstName\": \"pee\",\n"
                + "  \"lastName\": \"skillet\",\n"
                + "  \"other\": {\n"
                + "    \"age\": 100,\n"
                + "    \"birthday\": \"yesterday\"\n"
                + "  }\n"
                + "}";
        Response response = target("model").request().post(Entity.json(json));
        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
            System.out.println(response.getStatus() + ": " + response.readEntity(String.class));
            fail("should return data and 200");
        } else {
            Model model = response.readEntity(Model.class);
            JSONObject other = model.other;
            System.out.println(other.toString());
            assertEquals("pee", model.firstName);
            assertEquals("skillet", model.lastName);
            assertEquals(100, other.getInt("age"));
            assertEquals("yesterday", other.getString("birthday"));
        }
    }
}
```

What you should also do is get rid of *all* the Jackson dependencies you have in your comment above. You only need one dependency for Jackson JSON support.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
</dependency>
```

Also notice the `ObjectMapperProvider` in the test. You will need to this to register the `JsonOrgModule` with the `ObjectMapper` in order for Jackson to be able to handle `JSONObject`. This is important. If you don't have the `ContextResolver`, the above example will fail.

Comment: Thank u very much. As per your advice, I added the `ObjectMapperProvider` class for registering the `JsonOrgModule` with `ObjectMapper`. How do I link it with `someClass` ?

Comment: @vardhinisuresh27 You don't need to link anything. As long as the `ObjectMapperProvider` is registered, it should work, as seen in my complete runnable/testable example

Comment: Thank you. But I see from ur test code that the `configure()` function has registration of the `ObjectMapperProvider`. So how do I go about something like that in my case?

Comment: I don't know, you have not shown your case. I don't know how you register all your resource classes and providers. Are you using package scanning? If so, the scanning should pick up the `@Provider` annotation and register it for you, as long as the class is in the packages or sub-package listed to be scanned.

Comment: Also keep in mind that you should get rid of all the Jackson dependencies you have in your post. Just use the one I have in my answer

Comment: I've posted the way I've registered resource classes and providers in `web.xml` above as part of my other snippets. Also, as you have told before, I removed all the unnecessary Jackson dependencies! Thanks for your responses.

Comment: Thank u very much for your guidance! It works now. I forgot to register `JacksonFeature` along with the `ObjectMapperProvider`

Comment: I'm wondering how to make this work outside of glassfish? I have a class extending Application with a list of classes and singletons. I'm adding the ObjectMapperProvider to my list of classes, but JSONObjects still only render as a blank string.

Comment: @Amalgovinus You need to disable MOXy, which is the default provider. Or you can register JacskonFeature. This will also disabled MOXy implicitly

Comment: JacksonFeature seems to be a glassfish thing?  (org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature)

Comment: The whole " implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>" totally breaks it for me, the JSONObject gets put out as a blank string rather than json.

Comment: It seems like my class implementing ContextResolver never has its getContext() called.  If I don't have the class providing my ObjectMapper implement ContextResolver, then I can GET json properly, but trying to POST or PUT it results in the backend receiving nothing. If I do implement ContextResolver, the value comes through as a blank string both ways. Pretty confusing. Is this ContextResolver stuff only needed for Jersey and not just plain Jackson / Swagger?

Comment: @Amalgovinus As I said, in Glassfish, MOXy is the default provider. The ContextResolver for ObjectMapper isn't used for MOXy. You need to disabled MOXy if you want to use Jackson

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'm not using glassfish / jersey, so I'm guessing MOXy isn't being used either unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @Amalgovinus Unfortunately this isn't something I can really figure out for you with this little information. I'm not sure why the resolver is not called. If you are using the Jackson "provider", then it _will_ call the resolver. You need to make sure you're using the provider and that it is registered and the one being used.

Comment: You're right that it wasn't, thanks. I got it working without ContextResolver so that must just be jersey thing.

Comment: You remove dependencies when you are testing? So, for running and for testing you use different pom?