# Passing Json to Rest and receiving it through JSONObject

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, jersey

I am having the following server side code:-

```
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    @Path("/user")
    public class Users {

    @POST
    @Path("register")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response registerUser(JSONObject userDetails) {
        return Response.status(Status.ACCEPTED).entity("User Created.Details are: " + userDetails).build();
    }
}
```

Once I tried to call this using the following I am getting a 415 error. Can you please let me know what is the way to solve this.

```
{
    "user_id": "masha@meeshka.com",
    "password": "mashakawa",

    "user_profile": {
        "name": "Masha",
        "city": "New York",
        "email": "maasha@kawa.com",
        "age": 20
    },

    "user_settings": {
        "phone_number": "+91898342123"
    }
}
```

By the way i am using Jersey.

Comment: Maybe you sent your request with media-type "text/plain" instead of "application/json" ?

Comment: It should be `Response.status(Status.ACCEPTED).entity(userDetails).build();`

"User Created.Details are: " + userDetails will concatenate string with userDetails will make the object string not the bean object.

Comment: [See Also](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32942810/2587435)

Answer (score 2):

In JAX-RS, you will have to create a JSON `MessageBodyReader` that will `readFrom` `InputStream` and return a `JSONObject`.

```
@Provider
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JSONObjectMessageBodyReader implements MessageBodyReader<JSONObject> {

    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return true;
    }

    public JSONObject readFrom(Class<T> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream) throws java.io.IOException, javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException {
        //Using entityStream, read the content and return a  JSONObject back...
        BufferedReader streamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entityStream, "UTF-8")); 
        StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        String inputStr;
        while ((inputStr = streamReader.readLine()) != null)
            responseStrBuilder.append(inputStr);

        return new JSONObject(responseStrBuilder.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1939366 I didn't know you couldn't take an `InputStream` to `JSONObject`. I assumed you could. Please see my updated post.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do that is --

```
public void parseJson(WebResource service) throws UniformInterfaceException, JSONException {

  JSONArray resultArray = new JSONArray(service.path("resources/test/json/Tom").get(String.class));

  List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();

  for (int count = 0; count < resultArray.length(); count++) {

    JSONObject userObject = resultArray.getJSONObject(count);
    // this is tor read a sample JSON., this code will change according to your need.
    User user = new User(userObject.get("name").toString(), userObject.get("surname").toString(), userObject.get("address").toString()); 

    userList.add(user);

  }

  System.out.println(userList);

 }
```

This code is written specifically for Jersey web services.

Please find more links for coding in Jersey  -

[Creating Webservices with Maven and Jersy](http://javacodingtutorial.blogspot.de/search/label/Jersey)

Edit : (Client needs java-json.jar in it's classpath to develop this code).