# Facing Exception of MessageBodyWriter while sending JSONObject to Rest web service

Tags: jersey-client, jersey-1.0

I am newbie to web service. Due to requirement I have to send a file[most probably in txt format] to server through REST web service.

**I am getting the exception like below.**

MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class gvjava.org.json.JSONObject, genericType=class gvjava.org.json.JSONObject.

**Here is my web service method.**

```
@Path("{c}")
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String convert(@PathParam("c") JSONObject object) throws JSONException {

    String result = "";     
    return "<ctofservice>" +  "<ctofoutput>" + result + "</ctofoutput>" + "</ctofservice>";
}
```

**Now client code is like below**

```
JSONObject data_file = new JSONObject();
        data_file.put("file_name", uploadFile.getName());
        data_file.put("description", "Something about my file....");
        data_file.put("file", uploadFile);       

        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

        webTarget = client.target(uploadURL).path("ctofservice").path("convert");

          Response value = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .post(Entity.entity(data_file,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE),
                        Response.class);
```

Please help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

**------------------------------------------------------------------------**

As suggested by **peeskillet** in the answer below, I tried to send file through multipart. Still I am facing exception of **no octet stream found**.

**Below is my rest api**

```
@Path("{c}")
@POST   
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response convert(@FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition file) {

    String result = ""; 
Some operation with attached parameter ...
    return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
}
```

**Here is my test client**

```
FormDataMultiPart  multiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();
        multiPart.setMediaType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE);

        FileDataBodyPart fileDataBodyPart = new FileDataBodyPart("file",
            uploadFile,MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
        multiPart.bodyPart(fileDataBodyPart);

        Client client = Client.create();

        WebResource webResource = client
           .resource(uploadURL).path("ctofservice");

        ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
                   .post(ClientResponse.class,multiPart);

        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
           throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
            + response.getStatus());
        }
```

**And I am getting the exception below**

[image]
I am not able to understand why I need to send data as **MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE** ? As I have used multipart as media type before ...

I appreciate your help..

Comment: If you just want to upload a text file, then it is better to send the file as binary stream (Multipart). It will save you from handling of text file encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Without needing to configuring anything else, the easiest way to get around this is to just use a String instead of the actual `JSONObject` (i.e. just passing `toString()`)

```
.post(Entity.json(data_file.toString()))
```

The problem with using `JSONObject` is that there is no provider that knows how to handle the conversion. You will have the same problem on the server side, where there is no provider to handle the conversion to `JSONObject`. So you will need to just do

```
@POST
public Response post(String json) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
}
```

If you really want to be able to just use `JSONObject` without needing to use a String, then you should check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32942810/jsonobject-as-a-member-variable-in-pojo-not-recognized-jersey/32986836#32986836).

As an aside, this is not valid JSON (it's XML)

```
"<ctofservice>" +  "<ctofoutput>" + result + "</ctofoutput>" + "</ctofservice>"
```

but you are saying that the endpoint returns JSON

Comment: I have to send files. If I convert it to string then url string will be too large.

Comment: If you're sending files, then why are you using JSON? Use MultiPart instead

Comment: The idea is , copy each line of file into List<String> at client . Then pass it to web service. Can I achieve it through MultiPart ?

Comment: Yes, you will just send the the binary file.

Comment: Ok let me try with it. Thanks for suggestion.