# Java Jersey Web Service: consume JSON request

Tags: java, angularjs, json, rest, jersey

I have a web service made witj Java and Jersey. I want to receive a JSON request and parse the json for savethe values stores on the json on the database.

This is mi web service code:

```
@Path("companies")
public class Companies {

    @Path("add")
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public JSONObject addCompanies(JSONObject inputJsonObj){

        String input = (String) inputJsonObj.get("company");
        String output = "The input you sent is :" + input;
        JSONObject outputJsonObj = new JSONObject();
        outputJsonObj.put("output", output);

        return outputJsonObj;
    }
}
```

The client side is made with AngularJS:

```
$scope.company = "";
    $scope.submit = function(){
        // Writing it to the server
        //      
        var dataObj = {
                company : $scope.company
        };  
        var res = $http.post('http://localhost:8080/WS-Test2/crunchify/companies/add', dataObj);
        res.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.message = data;
            notify("succes");
        });
        res.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            //alert( "failure message: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
            notify("fail");
        });
    };
```

This is the error I'm getting when I pass the JSON to the web service:

```
Status Code:415
```

And this is the request I am sending:

```
{"company":"Testing2"}
```

This is my Network tab:

[image]

Comment: mm it looks strange .. i have done a little research about the error code 415 ..and it looks like the format is not supported..so..are you sure about how you set the json type of your back end api? maybe with something like @Consumes ({MediaType. APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType. APPLICATION_JSON})

Comment: I tried with @Consumes ({MediaType. APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType. APPLICATION_JSON}) but I'm getting the same error

Comment: mm looks strange cause Angular $http.post send for default json... so i can guess the problem is in the back end configuration..but i don't know java :-)

Comment: Go to your **browser's developer tools Network tab and click on the respective service call**. Take a **screenshot** and update to your question.

Comment: @Aravind I posted

Comment: @Aravind no I'm sorry

Comment: @Aravind explain me what could be wrong and I will try to fix it, I need to learn for myself. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further configuration, `JSONObject` is not something that Jersey supports. You will just need to work with Strings

```
public String addCompanies(String json){
    JSONObject inputJsonObj = new JSONObject(json)

    String input = (String) inputJsonObj.get("company");
    String output = "The input you sent is :" + input;
    JSONObject outputJsonObj = new JSONObject();
    outputJsonObj.put("output", output);

    return outputJsonObj.toString();
}
```

If you really want to use `JSONObject` you can check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32986836/2587435).

**See Also:**

- [JAX-RS Entity Providers](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html) to learn how Jersey handle serialization an deserialization.

Comment: Yes is working, I'll check JAX-RS Entity Providers post anyway to implement it. Thanks!