# JSONObject sent via JerseyTest coming blank

Tags: java, jersey

I am using `Jersey 3.0.3`. I am doing a unit test and posting an `org.json.JSONObject`. When I am receiving it in my endpoint the `JSONObject` is coming as a blank object. This issue is happening even when I send the POST request via Postman. How do I fix this?

My Unit Test:

```
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class IgnoredItemPositiveTests extends JerseyTest {
    
    private String itemId;
    private JSONObject item;
    
    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        itemId = "id1";
        item = new JSONObject();
        item.put("item_id", "id1");
        item.put("item_title", "title1");
        return new ResourceConfig(IgnoredItemService.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void ItemInsert_ItemIdNotPresent_Inserted() {
        System.out.println(item); // prints {"item_id":"id1","item_title":"title1"}
        Response response = target("ignored-item").request()
                .post(Entity.json(item));

        assertEquals("Http Response should be 201: ", Status.CREATED.getStatusCode(), response.getStatus());
    }
}
```

My Endpoint:

```
@Path("/ignored-item")
public class IgnoredItemService {
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response create(JSONObject item) {
        System.out.println(item); // prints {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Jersey does not support org.json by default. Instead, jakarta.json (JSON-P) is supported.

Comment: @jan.supol How do I do it using that?

Comment: Jersey has documentation here: https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest3x/media.html#json

Comment: @jan.supol Is there a marshaller for org.json and jersey? Or do I have to write one myself?

Comment: I am not aware of any. If you want to use org.json, a provider needs to be registered with Jersey: https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest3x/message-body-workers.html

Comment: There is a provider. You use Jackson along with its org.json support module

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32986836/2587435